# Quicktags on all textarea.. Not working on plugin?

Tags: tags, buttons, input, quicktag

I want to put a couple of quicktags/buttons on a textarea which is outputted by a plugin called **user submitted posts**. I have given this textarea an unique id and read this on the Quicktags documentation:

> - Run quicktags(settings) to initialize it, where settings is an object containing up to 3 properties:
> - settings = {
> - id : 'my_id',          the HTML ID of the textarea, required
> - buttons: ''            Comma separated list of the names of the default buttons to show. Optional.
> - Current list of default button names: 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,more,spell,close';
> - }
>     *
> - The settings can also be a string quicktags_id.
>     *
> - quicktags_id string The ID of the textarea that will be the editor canvas
> - buttons string Comma separated list of the default buttons names that will be shown in that instance.

Than, I put this in my **functions.php**:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts','my_admin_print_footer_scripts');
function my_admin_print_footer_scripts()
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */

    var id = "myID"; // this is your metabox's textarea id

    settings = {
        id : id,
        buttons: 'strong,em,link' 
    }

    quicktags(settings);

/* ]]> */</script>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem: nothing shows up.

PS: I already looked here: [Use quicktags toolbar on any textarea](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44993/use-quicktags-toolbar-on-any-textarea)

Can someone make a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to make it work with a different plugin. Solution: use Javascript like [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272451/make-tags-from-text-and-textarea-fields-content-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

it you're not seeing the buttons, try to call QTags._buttonsInit(); right after you call the quicktags( settings ); function.

```
quicktags(settings);
QTags._buttonsInit();
```

Following also works for me

```
qt_editor = new QTags( { 'id': 'my_editor', 'buttons': 'strong,em,link' } );
QTags._buttonsInit();
```

Also, it seems that adding a button via QTags.addButton() function also makes your toolbar to display

```
qt_editor = new QTags( { 'id': 'my_editor', 'buttons': 'strong,em,link' } );
QTags.addButton( 'my_button', 'my button', '<br />' );
```